# .Next To remove limitation on data send using JSONP

Tags: javascript, json

Can we remove the limitation on data send using JSONP. Below is my code. What i am trying to do is to pass 3000 characters(actuallly a image which is converted to base64 data) at a time to service(serviceCall.ashx). As my data is large up to 30,000-40,000 characters i am dividing it in packets(3000 each ) and then sending it. Is there any way i can send this complete data in one go. Reason for switching to JSONP is to avoid the pop up on IE which says 'This page is accessing info that is not.....'. I know as JSONP uses GET method there would obviously a data limitation but is there any way to work around this problem.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  'http://sys108/restnew1/serviceCall.ashx',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    data: { 
        datachunk: imgdatachunk,
        packetlen: imgdatachunk.length, 
        imagekey: imageid 
    },
    success: function (data) {},
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (window.console) 
            console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to send a GET request of that length in a more-or-less reliable way: actually, it depends both on how the web server is set up and what client (= browser) is used by someone who works with your application.

So I'd suggest looking for alternative (to JSONP) solutions - like [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/), for example.